# For i Loop and For each loop just not jumping as I want VBA

Tags: vba, loops

I created this VBA Code but it does not loop through each worksheet as I want it to. I just perform the task on the active worksheet. 
Could someone help me out?

```
Public Sub MvColumns()

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Columns("D:D").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Columns("F:F").Select
        Selection.Cut Destination:=Columns("D:D")
        Columns("F:F").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Columns("G:G").Select
        Selection.Cut Destination:=Columns("J:J")
        Columns("H:H").Select
        Selection.Cut Destination:=Columns("G:G")
        Columns("H:J").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Columns("A:F").Select
        Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 18.43
        Range("C4").Select
        Range("A2").ClearContents
Next


End Sub
code here
```

Comment: You need to watch this video: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=5&t=3128s)

Answer (score 0):

Your code just perform the task on the active sheet because by default

```
Columns("D:D").Select
```

and the other lines are applied to the active sheet.

To apply a task to a selected sheet you have to prefix your code by using "With"  like this

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyWantedSheet")
    .Columns("D:D").Select 'the dot link your code with "MyWantedSheet"
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
     'your entire code
End With
```

In your case, you're using a loop so you can do that :

```
For each sheet in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' loop over all sheets 
    With sheet 'select the sheet and apply task on it
         .Columns("D:D").Select
         Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
         'your entire code
    End With
Next
```

Comment: You already have a reference to the sheet with your `For Each...`, you don't need to use `With ThisWorkBook.Sheets(sheet.name)`, just use `With sheet`.

Comment: Thank you. That is the right method and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch this video series: [Excel VBA Introduction - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  This is the most relavent: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=5&t=3128s)

```
Public Sub MvColumns()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
            .Columns("D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            .Columns("F").Cut Destination:=Columns("D:D")
            .Columns("F").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            .Columns("G").Cut Destination:=Columns("J:J")
            .Columns("H").Cut Destination:=Columns("G:G")
            .Columns("H:J").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            .Columns("A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            .Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
            .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 18.43
            .Range("A2").ClearContents
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your **Dim** and **For** lines with:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
```

That should accomplish what you're asking -- but if you like, you could also clean up unnecessary parts of your code (and speed it up slightly) like this:

```
Public Sub MvColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Columns("D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        ws.Columns("F").Cut Destination:=Columns("D")
        ws.Columns("F").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        ws.Columns("G").Cut Destination:=Columns("J")
        ws.Columns("H").Cut Destination:=Columns("G")
        ws.Columns("H:J").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        ws.Columns("A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        ws.Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        ws.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 18.43
        ws.Range("A2").ClearContents
    Next
End Sub
```